# Correctly using source-map for visual code using webpack

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, webpack, source-maps

Hello I am trying debug js code using Visual code. Visual code not stoping at breakpoint complaining its not able to find proper .

My webpack config looks like this

```
{
        'mode': mode,
        entry: {
            lapp: './src/app.js',
        },  
        devtool: 'source-map',
        output: {
            path: path.join(__dirname, 'build'),
            filename: '[name].js',
            publicPath: "/build/",
            libraryTarget: 'umd',
            library: 'LAPP'
        }

    },
```

Visual code debug config looks like

```
 "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [

        {
            "name": "Launch localhost",
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/examples/livebuild/lapps.html",
            "webRoot": "/Users/name/Sites/LappsInternal/
        },
    ]
```

On exceuting .scripts  from visual code says

```
-webpack://LAPPS/./src/app.js (/Users/name/Sites/LappsInternal/build/webpack:/LAPPS/src/app.js)
```

Any suggestion? There similar issue reported for visual-code in github but solutions not helping

Comment: update `devtool` config with `devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map'` and then try

Comment: Hey Thanks, Its working :)

Comment: let me add this as an answer. Hope u will accept it and maybe upvote :p

Comment: Sure! Good news visual code is stoping at the line, however in the breakpoint list it says breakpoint set but not yet  bound

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update `devtool` config with `devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map'`.

```
{
    'mode': mode,
    entry: {
        lapp: './src/app.js',
    },  
    devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'build'),
        filename: '[name].js',
        publicPath: "/build/",
        libraryTarget: 'umd',
        library: 'LAPP'
    }
},
```